# how to change the value of a global variable within a inner class

Tags: java

i have this function to retrieve access token from the server

```
public void retrieveAccessTokenfromServer() {
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("http://2401a7dd.ngrok.io/token")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        String identity = result.get("identity").getAsString();
                        VideoActivity.this.accessToken=result.get("token").getAsString();
                        debug.setText(VideoActivity.this.accessToken);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this,
                                R.string.error_retrieving_access_token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }

                }
            });

}
```

Outside that function at the top i have a global variable 'String accessToken' which i want to assign it with an access token from the server using this function. My problem is that the global variable does not take the value assigned to it in onCompleted method. I believe this is because it is used in inner class that why it can not take any value. The debug.set is working properly as it is, but if i put it ouside is printing nothing

Any help how to change the value of a global variable within a inner class

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "global".  We could spend some time trying to sort out the terminology, but the quickest thing might be for you to show enough code that we can see how the variable is declared.

Comment: Change `VideoActivity.this.accessToken=result.get("token").getAsString();` to `accessToken = result.get("token").getAsString();` if `accessToken` is declared as a global field

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: Agreed, although `VideoActivity.this.accessToken` makes it fairly clear it's an instance field in the containing class.

Comment: An inner class can set the value of a non-`final` instance field in its containing class. (And you'll get a compile-time error if it's `final`.) It won't just silently fail, so I find it hard to believe you're not getting any compile-time or runtime error assigning to `VideoActivity.this.accessToken`, but that you're also not seeing its value get changed. Please reduce the problem to a [mcve] and post that to the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - If you said that line *suggests* it's an instance field in the containing class, I'd agree; but considering various inconsistencies (terminology used, the points you raise in your other comment) I find it better not to assume that without clarification; which is why I didn't just post an answer

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: Absolutely, don't waste time answering an unclear question. I can't think of any way `VideoActivity.this.accessToken = x` isn't a compilation error if it's not a non-`final` instance field, but see my note above, I'm having trouble buying the premise of the question. :-) For all we know, there *is* a compilation error. Best not to guess.

Comment: guys..thank you for the response but the accessToken is indeed not declared as final and not having any compiling errors..it as declared like this: private String accessToken; first line under: public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {...}. The problem is that i want to assign it a value from the function posted..basically it gets assigned only inside the inner class..i want to assign that value from the  inner class and be there even if i go outside that function

Comment: I FOUND my solution..the problem was that i was not giving some time to the function to load the token. as a result the function connectToRoom(accesstoken) was getting null. i put the connectToRoom(accesstoken) in a hander with 2 seconds and it worked. Thank you anyway for your answers